# Use Identity-Authentication and Cookie-Authentication together in a row ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm setting up a new ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application. I would like to have two separate authentication procedures in a row. First, you register as a company where there is only one registration data for the entire company, and therefore the same for each employee. Once entered in the "company area", then the actual login screen for each employee appears.

For the company login I would like to use the Identity authentication.
For the employees' second authentication procedure I would like to use the cookie authentication, so that the employees can easily loggin and logout but are still inside their "company environment".

Does anyone knows how to configure these two authentication procedures, so that I'm able to use them together in a row?

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // 1. Authentication for the companies (tenants)
            services.AddIdentity<Tenant, Role>(options =>
                {
                    // Password settings.
                    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                    options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
                    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDataContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

                    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                    options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                });


            // 2. Authentication for the employees (users)
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

                    options.LoginPath = "/Users/Login";
                    options.LogoutPath = "/Users/Logout";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Users/AccessDenied";
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;

                    options.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);
                });

            services.AddScoped<CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents>();



            services.AddMvc(config =>
                {
//little trial two add both schemes to the AuthorizationPolicyBuilder, but does not really work... 
                    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build(); // 1.Tenants, 2.User
                    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Until now only the login screen for the Tenant (company - Identity) appears. It does not force me to login also as a user (employee - cookie authentication).
Thanks a lot.